# Como ordenar o meu gráfico de barras por dia da semana no R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Olá, Boa tarde.

Preciso de uma ajuda para ordenar por dia da semana no R o meu gráfico de barras, conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que utilizei é o seguinte:

date_manip %>%
na.omit() %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Dia_semana), group=1) +
geom_bar(aes(x=Dia_semana)) +
ggtitle("Viagens por dia da semana") +
theme_clean()

Obrigado,

Wil

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você pode ordenar os dados por dia da semana:

`date_manip$Dia_semana <- ordered(date_manip$Dia_semana, levels=c("domingo", "segunda-feira", "terça-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira", "sexta-feira", "sábado"))`

E depois o gráfico:

`date_manip %>% na.omit() %>% ggplot(aes(x=Dia_semana), group=1) + geom_bar(aes(x=Dia_semana)) + ggtitle("Viagens por dia da semana") + theme_clean()`

Comment: Maravilha @Josiane Souza! Deu super certo. Muito obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Olá, basta alterar os dados utilizados no eixo X para fator.

Segue abaixo possível resolução:

date_manip %>% na.omit() %>% mutate(Dia_semana, levels = c("segunda-feira","terça-feira","quarta-feira","quinta-feria","sexta-feira","sábado","domingo")) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Dia_semana), group=1) + geom_bar(aes(x=Dia_semana)) + ggtitle("Viagens por dia da semana") + theme_clean()

Comment: Olá @hamers! A sua solução também é boa. Me ajudou muito! Obrigado